# MEAN js download file from system path

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I want to implement feature in [MEANJS](https://meanjs.org/) project to download mp3 files from system path

```
 Example: /usr/local/setup/file.mp3
```

I want to apply security checks for valid user and allow user to download mp3 files.

Is there any other way which can be used to download files with security?

Answer (score 0):

We can use below node js function

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
app.get('/api/download-music', function(req, res){

var filename = "file.mp3"; 

var filePath = path.join("/usr/local/setup/", filename);

var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);


res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3',
    'Content-Length': stat.size,
    "content-disposition":"attachment; filename="+filename
});

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

readStream.on('data', function(data) {
    var flushed = res.write(data);
    // Pause the read stream when the write stream gets saturated
    if(!flushed)
        readStream.pause();
});

res.on('drain', function() {
    // Resume the read stream when the write stream gets hungry 
    readStream.resume();    
});

readStream.on('end', function() {
    readStream
    .pipe(res);   
});


 });

 }
```

in above node js code we can apply security checks with session id.

on angular template we can use below html:

```
<a href="/api/download-music" download target="_self">Download</a>
```